# How to set dependency scope in sbt according to profile?

Tags: scala, sbt, dependency-management

How to set dependency in build.sbt according to different envs. For example:

```
libraryDependencies ++= "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "compile", // expected  in dev
libraryDependencies ++= "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "provided", // expected in prod
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set the environment identifier in system properties and use scala match in `build.sbt` to get desired results.

Your build.sbt should look like this :-

```
val mode = sys.env.getOrElse("EXEC_MODE", "dev") // can be hardcoded.
val devSparkVersion = 2.0.2
val prodSparkVersion = 1.6.2

mode match {
  case "dev"  => libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % devSparkVersion
  case "prod" => libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % prodSparkVersion
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried this but according to this documentation:

http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Configuring-Scala.html

It looks like if you set

```
autoScalaLibrary := false
```

Then you can either use "test", "compile" or "runtime"